# handling the data in the nested tags and grouping them in xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I need some clarification on XSLT how to do the following in XSLT.

I have the source file as this.

```
<Data>
    <additem>                   
                <choice>desc</choice>
                <sectiontext>
                    <a title="google" href="http://google.com" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                        <strong>Sample Text</strong>
                        <ul>
                            <li><em>aa</em></li>
                            <li><em>bb</em></li>
                            <li><em>cc</em></li>
                        </ul>
                    </a>                        
                </sectiontext>

    </additem>
    <additem>   
                <choice>image</choice>
                <files>
                    <a xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" title="image location" href="xyz:12-2022">
                        <img  alt="No Image" title="No Image" xlink:href="some image path" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"></img>
                    </a>
                </files>
    </additem>
            <additem>                   
                <choice>Paragraph</choice>
                <sectiontext>
                    <a title="google" href="http://google.com" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                        <strong>Sample Text</strong>
                        <ul>
                            <li><em>aa</em></li>
                            <li><em>bb</em></li>
                            <li><em>cc</em></li>
                        </ul>
                    </a>
                    hello alll

                </sectiontext>

    </additem>
</Data>
```

Output:

```
<Information>

        <Section>
            <text>
                <strong>Sample Text</strong>
                        <ul>
                            <li><em>aa</em></li>
                            <li><em>bb</em></li>
                            <li><em>cc</em></li>
                        </ul>
            </text>
            <link external="http://google.com" title="google"></link>
        </Section>
        <picture>
            <image src="some image path" altText="No Image">
                <link local="xyz:12-2022" title="image location"></link>
            </image>
        </picture>
        <Body>
            <text>
                <hyperlink>
                    <text>
                        <strong>Sample Text</strong>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><em>aa</em></li>
                                    <li><em>bb</em></li>
                                    <li><em>cc</em></li>
                                </ul>
                    </text> 
                    <link external="http://google.com" title="google"></link>
                </hyperlink>
                hello alll
            </text>
        </Body>
</Information>
```

Rules:

1.Depending on the choice in addItem/choice, we need to create the tag.

```
    choice    --    Desc
    desc    --      Section
    image   --      picture
    Paragraph----Body
```

2.Handling  tag
        Currently  tag is wrapping for some other tag.

```
    A.If any element has only <a> in it. For example in the source,

            Code in the source:
            <sectiontext>
                    <a title="google" href="http://google.com" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                        <strong>Sample Text</strong>
                        <ul>
                            <li><em>aa</em></li>
                            <li><em>bb</em></li>
                            <li><em>cc</em></li>
                        </ul>
                    </a>                        
            </sectiontext>
```

Need to seperate that tag and create a tag

```
i. if the "href" in attribute in <a> tag starts with "xyz:" need to add it as "local" attribute in <link> element
ii. If the "href" in the attribute <a> tag starts with "http" need to add it as "external" attribute in <link> element.
ii. "title" attribute in <a> tag remains same in <link>

    B.if any element has any other element other than <a> tag.

        Code in the source:

        <sectiontext>
                    <a title="google" href="http://google.com" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                        <strong>Sample Text</strong>
                        <ul>
                            <li><em>aa</em></li>
                            <li><em>bb</em></li>
                            <li><em>cc</em></li>
                        </ul>
                    </a>
                    hello alll

        </sectiontext>
```

I need to get the out put as

```
        <text>
                <hyperlink>
                    <text>
                        <strong>Sample Text</strong>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><em>aa</em></li>
                                    <li><em>bb</em></li>
                                    <li><em>cc</em></li>
                                </ul>
                    </text> 
                    <link external="http://google.com" title="google"></link>
                </hyperlink>
                hello alll
        </text>
```

Rules:

```
  i. In the all the text inside the <a> tag have to come under the <inlinelink> tag as shown above.
```

Can any one help how it can be done.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This XSLT 1.0 style-sheet ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                              xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
 <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
 <Information>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="Data/additem"/>
 </Information>
</xsl:template>      

<xsl:template match="xhtml:a[../../self::additem]">
 <link title="{@title}">
  <xsl:if test="starts-with(@href,'http')">
    <xsl:attribute name="external"><xsl:value-of select="@href" /></xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="starts-with(@href,'xyz:')">
    <xsl:attribute name="local"><xsl:value-of select="@href" /></xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:if>
 </link>
</xsl:template>      

<xsl:template match="additem[choice='desc']">
 <Section>
  <text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="sectiontext/xhtml:a/*" /> 
  </text>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="sectiontext/xhtml:a" />
 </Section>
</xsl:template>      

<xsl:template match="additem[choice='image']">
 <picture>
  <image src="{files/xhtml:a/xhtml:img/@xlink:href}" altText="{files/xhtml:a/xhtml:img/@alt}">
   <apply-templates select="files/xhtml:a" />
  </image>
 </picture>
</xsl:template>      

<xsl:template match="additem[choice='Paragraph']">
 <Body>
  <text>
   <hyperlink>
    <text>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="sectiontext/xhtml:a/*" />
    </text> 
    <xsl:apply-templates select="sectiontext/xhtml:a" />
   </hyperlink>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="sectiontext/node()[not(self::xhtml:a)]" />
  </text>
 </Body>
</xsl:template>      

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

... will transform your specified input document into this output document ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Information xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <Section>
    <text>
      <strong xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">Sample Text</strong>
      <ul xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                            <li><em>aa</em></li>
                            <li><em>bb</em></li>
                            <li><em>cc</em></li>
                        </ul>
    </text>
    <link title="google" external="http://google.com" />
  </Section>
  <picture>
    <image src="some image path" altText="No Image">
      <apply-templates select="files/xhtml:a" />
    </image>
  </picture>
  <Body>
    <text>
      <hyperlink>
        <text>
          <strong xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">Sample Text</strong>
          <ul xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                            <li><em>aa</em></li>
                            <li><em>bb</em></li>
                            <li><em>cc</em></li>
                        </ul>
        </text>
        <link title="google" external="http://google.com" />
      </hyperlink>

                    hello alll

                </text>
  </Body>
</Information>
```

---

## Explanation

Each of your rules was taken one by one and used to build a template, starting with the identification of the match condition.